# integrate Accelerated Mobile Pages in vivvo template

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am working on vivvo template. Which is completed, now I have to integrate Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) in it. To reference amp js file use this

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

but this file did't included in pages. And all reference files css and js after this line didn't loaded. I followed this link to use amp
[Create Your First AMP Page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create_page.html)
What am i missing. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start you can't use **any** other CSS files (inline CSS only) nor Javascript.

What do you mean "this file did't included in pages"? That piece of javascript is mandatory on an AMP page (it's what makes it an AMP page).

Also have you used the #development=1 option in Google Chrome? Append that to your URL and then reload the page with Developer tools open and look at the console to see errors.

I've blogged my own experiences creating AMP pages here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/implementing-accelerated-mobile-pages/ as there were a few funnies I didn't realise until I started implementing them.